# Image 2x downsampling with Lanczos filter

Tags: image-processing, filtering, signal-processing, image-scaling, lanczos

I'm trying to implement image downsampling with Lanczos2.

However, the kernel seems to have zeros everywhere (since sin(pi*x)=0 if x is integer) [except at the center pixel](http://www.realitypixels.com/turk/computergraphics/ResamplingFilters.pdf).

Thus, if the downsampling factor is an integer number (e.g. the output size is 1/2 of the original size at each dimension), then the Lanczos downsampling yields the exact same result as nearest neighbor interpolation (just taking every other pixel in 2X downsampling).

I believe that this is not intended to be the case, so my question is:
What am I missing?

How to use lanczos2 filter for 2x downsampling and is the result expected to be different than simply take every other pixel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The kernel for 2x downsampling is given in section "Decimation by factor of 2 with the Lanczos2 sinc function" on page 10 of the [reference you linked](http://www.realitypixels.com/turk/computergraphics/ResamplingFilters.pdf), with the coefficients:

```
0, -0.032, 0, 0.284, 0.496, 0.284, 0, -0.032, 0
```

This kernel is obtained by evaluating the given lanczos2(x) function at values of `x=0.5n` where `n` is the sample number (an integer). This reflect the fact that the output rate is half the original sampling rate (thus requires a half-band filter before pixel decimation to avoid aliasing).

P.S.: the kernel with zeros everywhere except at the center pixel that you have obtained, would typically be used (although implementations would usually optimize this kernel out as a simple pixel copy) in conjunction with a phase 1/2 kernel for *interpolation* by a factor 2.